# How do you quantify snowfalls?

Tags: word-request

In my native language, it is common to describe the heaviness of a snowfall by the height of the accumulated snow on the ground.

Literally it would translate like

- Yesterday there was a snowfall. The snow has accumulated 1m high.
- In this part of the country, we have lots of snow. Two or three times in a winter, we have 2m accumulation of snow.

I assume these are not very idiomatic. What do English speakers say to describe how much snow has fallen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English we also quantify snowfall (and rainfall!) in terms of height. In the US this is in inches and feet. But instead of talking about the *accumulation* we usually use the verb **receive** (or a synonym) in the passive voice:

> We received three inches of rain last night.
> Buffalo was hit by a heavy snowstorm and received two feet of snow.
> They usually get three feet of snow once or twice a winter.

Note that snow compresses as it accumulates, which means measuring the amount of snow received is not as simple as just going out the next morning with a yardstick. See the wiki article on [snow gauges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_gauge) for more information.

Comment: I think "fell" and  "fall" are more common than receive  
*Six inches of snow fell on buffalo.*" "*Today's snowfall was four inches*". "*It is predicted the nine inches of snow will fall n=tonight."*

Comment: So _accumulate_ usually doesn't collocate with _X inches of snow_?

Comment: @sundowner - *Accumulate* is not generally used in the U.S. to describe precipitation amounts.  There are some particular times where it might be said.   For example a TV weather-person might say, *Total accumulation amount for this weekend's snowstorm is predicted to be between two and three feet.*  If you used *accumulation* you would be understood.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the terms used are "heavy" (for more) and "light" (for less).

These work for other types of precipitation as well (e.g. rain). More snow = more weight, and so is "heavier".

So, for example a "light shower of rain" (I'm from a hot area, so we very rarely get snow outside of the mountains) might leave on slightly wet, whereas a very "heavy rain" might lead to flash floods.

Comment: For those of us not from a hot area, it's perfectly normal to refer to 'six inches of snow'.

Answer (score 1):

You could say "6 inches of snow has accumulated", but not "it has accumulated 6 inches".  Also "deep" is more likely than "high": The snow is 6 inches deep. "Accumulate" sounds rather technical to me. But living in the South of England, I don't have that much experience with deep snot.

Some expressions that seem idiomatic:

> Ten centimetres of snow fell last night.

> We are forecasting over a foot of snow in the North.

> The snow was a metre deep in places.

> Blizzard conditions have led to snow drifts of six feet.